# IBM MobileFirst. Does MFP Cordova project support DirectUpdate?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

`mfp -v 7.1.0.00.20160206-1603`
My project was created using `mfp cordova ...` syntax.
I cannot configure DirectUpdate.
- Building .wlapp with the same version.
- Deploying to production server.
- And nothing. No popup. App connects to server. Everything works as if update was not there.

So the question is: Does new `mfp cordova ...` project support DirectUpdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Direct Update is supported: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_cordova_vs_hybrid.html

The correct flow for Direct Update with MobileFirst-based Cordova applications is as follows:

1. "mfp cordova create" to create an application
2. "mfp cordova platform add" to add platform(s)
3. Update any web resources in the www folder
4. "mfp cordova build" (to populate the project with the web resources)

   (It is assume the application has a WL.Client.connect() method implemented)
5. "mfp push" to generate a .wlapp file and push it to the MobileFirst Server
6. "mfp cordova run" to run the application in device or emulator

Make additional changes to the web resources.
Repeat steps 4 and 5.

Open the existing app in the device/emulator (do **not** "mfp cordova run" again because that will overwrite the web resources on the device, in which case there won't be any direct update... because the checksum in the client and in the server will be the same).

To learn more about Direct Update: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/